# What happened to AppViewManager in Angular 2 Beta.16

Tags: angular

Until Beta.15 it just worked fine, but after updating to .16 today, It throws error on transpiling

> Error:(4, 9) TS2305: Module
>   `'"D:/............/node_modules/angular2/core"'` has no
>   exported member `'AppViewManager'`.

Is it removed/ replaced or shifted somewhere else ?

I tried to trace it in [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/969b55326c8281a9e4a3d850ee7e368a276c9d13?short_path=4ac32a7#diff-4ac32a78649ca5bdd8e0ba38b7006a1e) but couldn't. Did `node_modules/angular2` wide search in WebStorm with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

> AppViewManager is renamed into ViewUtils and is a mere private utility service.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta16-2016-04-26

But `ViewUtils` doesn't seem to provide the same methods.

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8277

Comment: `AppViewManager` had `getComponent(e: ElementRef)` function and I was using it to register a few components in shared global service, but `ViewUtils` doesn't seem to provide it anymore. What are my options ?

Comment: Currently investigating. See the issue link I added to the answer. Actually it's about `getHostElement()` but similar.

Comment: I see, even there isn't any response yet. waiting.... Thanks for your rapid response :)