# Re-map angular/core to @angular/core in Webpack

Tags: angular, import, angular-cli

The Codeblock component from **ng2-prism** package complains about not being able to find `angular/core` module. That is totally legit, because in my application built with angular-cli, the angular core package is available at the ampersand name (`@angular/core`).

What would be the cleanest way to somehow alias the reference?

Comment: Just in case someone runs into this problem: looks like ng2-prism has not been made compatible with the final release of Angular 2. It still refers to AppViewManager which had been renamed and is no longer exported under that name: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36888558/what-happened-to-appviewmanager-in-angular-2-beta-16

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following to your webpack config:

```
...
resolve: {
    ...
    alias: {
        "angular": path.resolve('./node_modules/@angular')
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It think I needed something like:

```
"baseUrl": "../node_modules",
"paths": {
   "angular2/*": ["@angular/*"]
}
```

in my tsconfig.json. I couldn't find `webpack.config.js` or `system.config.js` files in any of the maintainable and versionable locations.

I am saying "I think" because putting the above snippet alleviated the "cannot find module" errors, but the app still does not want to run because of ng2-prism errors. I believe the snippet might help someone though or push them in the right direction.